# Char array, char pointer, works in one case but not the other?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, copy

I have a case where I initialize a char pointer with a string. I get some behaviour that works in one case, but not the other. I will explain with 3 samples of code:

The **first** code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char* f = "test";
    printf("%s", f);//prints "test"
}
```

This code works fine, the point of including it is to show that we can initialize a char pointer with a string and print it fine.

The **second** code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void strcpy(char* dst, char* src) {
    int i = 0;
    do {
        *(dst + i) = *(src + i);

    } while (*(src + (i++)));
}

int main(void) {
    char first[] = "test2";
    char second[] = "test3";

    strcpy(second, first);

    printf("%s", second); //prints "test2"
}
```

This code also works fine. The point of including it is because the next line of code will not work.

The **third** code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void strcpy(char* dst, char* src) {
    int i = 0;
    do {
        *(dst + i) = *(src + i);

    } while (*(src + (i++)));
}

int main(void) {
    char first[] = "test4";
    char *second = "test5"; //ONLY THIS LINE IS CHANGED

    strcpy(second, first);

    printf("%s", second); //PRINTS NOTHING
}
```

Do you see why the third code prints nothing? It is just the combined of the first and the second sample, so I can't see why it doesn't work?

Comment: If your program doesn't do what you want, what does it instead? Do you get some messages about segmentation fault, abnormal program termination or anything else that indicates things went down recently? You should also run your program in a debugger. It should immediately tell you where such a segmentation fault was detected.

Comment: You might also want to check [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1641957/17398063) (It is not!)

Comment: I just tried that using Microsoft's C compiler and it prints "test4" as you would expect.

Comment: @Bop Thank you very much. Do you mean that I should have written "strcpy(&second[0], &first[0]);" instead?

Comment: @user - No. :-)  But the difference works both ways - an array is not a pointer, and a pointer is not an array. An array has storage for the data, a pointer does not.

Comment: The bug is in the realm of undefined behavior, meaning anything can happen. Also meaning that "I tried it with compiler x and got behavior y" is a rather uninteresting observation. [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Comment: user394334, Well framed question.

Comment: Modifying string literals (char *string = "literal") most likely leads to undefined behavior. When you reverse that back to muttable string, you can also shorten `void strcpy1(char* dst, char* src) { while (*src) *dst++ = *src++; }`

Comment: @OldBoy "it prints "test4" as you would expect". That expection is already the error.

Comment: *Do you mean that I should have written `strcpy(&second[0], &first[0]);` instead?* No, I just copied your code and it ran "out of the box".

Comment: @Gerhardh You are correct of course. I was merely pointing out that I got a different result. Knowing which compiler the questioner is working with would help.

Comment: @OldBoy knowing what compiler the OP is using is irrelevant. The 3rd example invoked undefined behaviour and changing the compiler version could very well change the result of this code.

Comment: @Gerhardh Sorry for the late reply. I didn't get any error messages or segmentations faults, the program ran normally, all that happened was the nothing was printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char *second = "test5";` initializes `second` to point to the first character of the array created by a string literal. About string literals, C 2018 6.4.5 7 says:

> … If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

Since your program attempts to modify the array when it calls `strcpy(second, first);`, the behavior of your program is not defined.

A common behavior of C implementations is to put the arrays of string literals in memory marked as read-only for the process, so attempting to modify such an array causes a memory access violation.

Compiler optimization may also cause other behaviors initially surprising to programmers as optimization may assume that no attempt to modify the array of a string literal occurs and hence may transform the program based on that assumption.